# How to apply classes effectively to dynamically created elements in a component? Without databindings

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am converting a old Angular 1 app to Angular 5. The app consists of d3 graphs in which I used a directives in Angular 1.0.

In converting the Angular 1 directive to Angular 5, I found that I can not create elements real time and have a class applied to the and the class style be effective.

for example, this will longer work. The class `curve` style is not applied:

line-chart.component.ts:

```
  // Add the value curve path.
  svg.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'curve')
    .attr('style', 'fill: none; stroke: steelblue; stroke-width: 1.5px')
    .attr('d', curve(curveData.timestamps))
```

line-chart.component.css

```
.curve {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

---

Instead I have to do this:

```
  svg.append('path')
    .attr('style', 'fill: none; stroke: steelblue; stroke-width: 1.5px')
```

With Angular 5 components, is there a way to create elements dynamically and effectively style them with classes? Without data bindings that is.

Comment: Does it explicitly have to be an inline style?